# Duplicated blocks of code in Incremental - how can I tell what is duplicated?

Tags: sonarqube

We are relying heavily on the incremental analysis, and I notice that the "duplicated blocks of code" - I think in all languages, but for sure in C#, C++
doesn't tell you where the duplication is, or even of what.
so basically you have to check-in (and fail a gated check-in...) before you understand what Sonar meant.

Anything we can do to know this during the incremental?
even running a third party utility will be fine...whatever can find the duplication.

Thanks,
Roy.

Comment: what version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: Sorry for my poor post details. here's everything:  Sonar server 4.5.4, C# 3.3, C++ 3.2 and Sonar-Runner 2.3.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way in preview mode to display duplication. As a side note in preview (and especially incremental) the duplication computation is unreliable. In upcoming version of SQ we will deeply rework preview mode so I'll try to keep this use case in mind.